# Set self-referencing defaults in JSON object (jQuery Plugin)

Tags: jquery, json, plugins, settings, defaults

So I am trying to write a jQuery plugin and I have three values that I would like to set the defaults for one is a simple numeric value the others can be set if the user wants, but if they do not set them they need to have a default value of whatever the first is set.

Here is a longer version of what I want

```
config.duration = 350;
config.closeDuration = closeDuration OR duration;
config.openDuration = openDuration OR duration;
```

Basically if they are not set default back to whatever the duration value is. Even if the value has been set by the user. (eg. duration = 500)

I am just wondering if there is anyway to streamline this?

```
jQuery.fn.lighthouse = function(settings) {
    var config = {
            containerSelector: 'a',
            childSelector: 'span',
            closeSelector: '.close',
            duration: 350,
            openDuration: config.duration,
            closeDuration: config.duration,
            secondaryDuration: 100,
            background: 'rgb(230, 230, 230)',
            backgroundOpacity: '0.7'
        };

    if (settings){
        config = $.extend(config, settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you want. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Basically I would like to set a certain setting that uses another default setting's value if the certain setting is not defined by the user.

A = some value;
If B is not set by user then B = A;

Comment: you can't really do it without checking the settings object, or defining those 2 properties right after you define `config` without them in it

Comment: @charlietfl But all the other settings work fine without checking the settings object. I just want to link three settings together if only one is defined.

Comment: right but they are conditional, the others aren't

Comment: @charlietfl Could you show me how to "defining those 2 properties right after you define config without them in it"?

Comment: @LeinardoSmtih Can't you simply check after the extend if their values are set?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon How do you mean?

Comment: I mean something like that : http://jsfiddle.net/mc3VT/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hj5wS/1/

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thank you both, it seems that you guys are both thinking the same thing. Cannot think why I did not see that... Thanks for your help.

Comment: @charlietfl Any ideas on how to mark this closed? Since both of you answered at the same time (and both are not in the answers section)?

Comment: @LeinardoSmtih Never close question that may help others later. Just write an answers and check the `community wiki` on the under the textarea at the right and then submit it and mark as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the optional values to null, one can then use an inline if statement to determine the value of the setting. Here is a combination of both Karl-André Gagnon and charlietfl answers:

```
jQuery.fn.lighthouse = function(settings) {
    var config = {
        containerSelector: 'a',
        childSelector: 'span',
        closeSelector: '.close',
        duration: 350,
        openDuration: null,
        closeDuration: null,
        secondaryDuration: 100,
        background: 'rgb(230, 230, 230)',
        backgroundOpacity: '0.7'
    };

    if (settings){
        config = $.extend(config, settings);
    }

    config.openDuration = config.openDuration || config.duration;
    config.closeDuration = config.closeDuration || config.duration;
}
```